# make list items get next to each other

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nested-lists

I have a menu with sub menus. I used nested uls to achive this. Now I'm facing this situation: I want all the items and subitems to be displayed horizontally at their respective level. The problem is that when an parent list has a children list, it's width grows so the next item at the same level goes far to the right.

To have things more clear here's a fiddle of what I'm taking about: http://jsfiddle.net/matias/n8gFT/

As you can see I would like to have the items B and C placed where the green dashed spaces are.

Is it possible to do this?

I would like to keep using nested uls and `display: inline-block` for itemes instead of `float: left`

**SAMPLE HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li>ITEM A
        <ul>
            <li>sub item A1</li>
            <li>sub item A2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ITEM B</li>
    <li>ITEM C</li>
</ul>
```

**SAMPLE CSS**:

```
ul{border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;}
li{display: inline-block; border: 1px solid blue; margin: 5px; padding: 10px; vertical-align: top;}
span{border: 1px dashed lime; margin: 0 10px; padding: 5px;}
```

**EDIT 1**: I forgot to tell you this: A, B and C have children. If I click on B, it's children are shown and A's and C's are hidden...and so on....

Comment: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: @EmilioGort I want an horizontal list, no vertical.

Comment: what happens when item B or C have sub items as well?

Comment: @tman good point! see my edit 1

Comment: added a fix would this work ?

Comment: Updated answer Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved what I was looking for using `display: table-cell` to the li's and reducing ul's width.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n8gFT/7/)

Answer (score 8):

We will start off with a little CSS

```
#menu > li.sub ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000em;
  left: 0px;
}


#menu li.sub ul li a {
  display: inline;
}

#menu > li.sub:hover ul {
  top: 3em;
}

#menu{
  text-align:left;
}

li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Finish with some HTML

```
<ul id="menu" >

  <li class="sub"> 
    ITEM A
    <ul>
      <li>sub A1</li>
      <li>sub A2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="sub">
    ITEM B
    <ul>
      <li>sub B1</li>
      <li>sub B2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="sub">
    ITEM C
    <ul>
      <li>sub C1</li>
      <li>sub C2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

and a JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/ShADm/28/

Comment: if you want put the whole code in another ul to bring it together! see http://jsfiddle.net/n8gFT/4/

Comment: that it's what I want visually, but it's not nested. And I need them to be nested for programming purposes.

Comment: could you use some php and achieve this

Comment: If thats not it i dont know what is! Till next time woooshhhhhh

Comment: That looks promising! You think that hierarchy can be done? I mean...that subitems appear at parent left, no all at left 0

Comment: give it a shot :) ... your going to have to spell out the problamo a little more for me....you want the items to start underneath the parent correct? Try removing that line and see if that's the desired look!

Answer (score 1):

You could style the lists that are being pushed over `of margin-left: -20px;` here is a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n8gFT/1/

Of course the amount it is pushed over can be edited by changing the `margin-left`

Comment: thanks, but the lists are dynamic. At first hand I don't know how many items would be. using an absolute margin will not work.

Comment: You can use PHP saying that if there is a subcategory then set the next list item to have a `margin-left` though if you did do that you would have to do the whole page in PHP

Answer (score -2):

Add a class to the sub lists and style them like this:

```
.sub { position: absolute; margin-left: -27px; }
```